# My url rewrite redirects to mydomain.com/var/www/clients/client3/web25/

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I'm trying to make a rewrite of a url on my joomla site. I have an extra page in there wiht some other stuff on it.

I have:

```
RewriteRule ^company/([^/]+) company?alias=$1 [NC]
```

where i want company/somecompany to show what the url company?alias=somecompany will give (not forward to it).

What i get instead is a redirection to:

http://www.mydomain.dk/var/www/clients/client2/web5/web/company?alias=somecompany

Also if i include a "-" like "company/some-company" it skips my rewrite and just goes to the joomla rewrite rules (and can't find the article)

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Rewritebase is not set. i have tried just uncommenting the "RewriteBase /" but it gives the same result

Answer (score 4):

You need to add a `RewriteBase`. When your rewrite rule's target doesn't start with a leading slash (making it an absolute URI), apache needs to guess whether it's a URI-path or a file-path, and it is incorrectly guessing that it's a file-path. Adding a base tells apache that it's a URI path.

```
RewriteBase /
```

or add a leading slash to your target: `/company/?alias=$1`

You also want to add a trailing slash to company and use the `[L]` flag:

```
RewriteRule ^company/([^/]+) company/?alias=$1 [L,NC]
```

The missing trailing slash may be the culprit that's causing mod_dir and `DirectorySlash` redirecting. And the `L` flag may be why the joomla rules are eventually getting applied.

Comment: This really is weird!

If i use [R,L] it redirects the url perfectly to the destination company?alias=something. But since i dont want a redirect but a rewrite, i really don't understand why the other flags don't work!

Answer (score 0):

Here is the working example:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteRule ^/?old-folder/(.*)$ /new-folder/$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

For more examples, check:

- [Learn Apache mod_rewrite: 13 Real-world Examples](https://www.sitepoint.com/apache-mod_rewrite-examples-2/)
- [Apache Conf Snippets for VS Code](https://github.com/hrdtbs/vscode-apacheconf-snippets/blob/master/snippets/apacheconf.json)